# Xcode CI - Bot script for uploading to Fabric gives error "Failed to Detect Build Environment"

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, xcode-bots

Trying to setup an Xcode CI Bot to build and upload my app to Fabric for beta distribution.

The bot builds and archives the app just fine, but fails on the Fabric upload script. Any suggestions?

**Log:**

```
IPA Path: /Users/XcodeServer/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-c7216425c354c42adb04283fc31b6348/ExportedProduct/MyApp.ipa
2016-11-17 12:40:23.967 uploadDSYM[55991:2048496] Fabric.framework/run 1.6.2 (205)
2016-11-17 12:40:23.972 uploadDSYM[55991:2048496] Launched uploader in validation mode
error: Fabric: Failed to Detect Build Environment
```

**Script:**

```
IPA_PATH="${XCS_PRODUCT}"
echo "IPA Path: ${IPA_PATH}"
"${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}"/MyApp/Pods/Fabric/run <API> <KEY> -ipaPath "${IPA_PATH}" -emails me@email.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. I was using the wrong script *(pulled from the app's build phase when setting up Fabric)*. You have to use the **crashlytics** script:

```
"${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}"/MyApp/Pods/Crashlytics/submit <API> <KEY> -ipaPath "${IPA_PATH}" -emails me@test.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this script in the Post-Integration Script Triggers

```
"${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}/Pods/Crashlytics/submit" <API> <KEY> -ipaPath "${XCS_PRODUCT}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Xcode Server 10

```
# Make the the encoding is correct
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Remove & Copy assets
rm -r ${XCS_SOURCE_DIR}/ipa
cp -R ${XCS_OUTPUT_DIR}/ExportedProduct/Apps/ ${XCS_SOURCE_DIR}/ipa/

# Release the archive
${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}/Pods/Crashlytics/submit <API> <Key> -ipaPath ${XCS_SOURCE_DIR}/ipa/AppName.ipa -groupAliases groupName -notifications YES
```

In my case, Xcode Server deletes all assets after archive.

So I added a 'copy' command in the script.